# java thread and sychronized

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Here is the code from  K&B Study Guide

```
class Account {
private int balance = 50;
public int getBalance() {
  return balance;
}
public void withdraw(int amount) {
  balance = balance - amount;
}
}

public class AccountDanger implements Runnable {
private Account acct = new Account();
public static void main (String [] args) {
  AccountDanger r = new AccountDanger();
  Thread one = new Thread(r);
  Thread two = new Thread(r);
  one.setName("Fred");
  two.setName("Lucy");
  one.start();
  two.start();
 }
 public void run() {
 for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
  makeWithdrawal(10);
  if (acct.getBalance() < 0) {
    System.out.println("account is overdrawn!");
  }
  }
  }
 private synchronized void makeWithdrawal(int amt) {
 if (acct.getBalance() >= amt) {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() 
                 + " is going to withdraw");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) { }
    acct.withdraw(amt);
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() 
                 + " completes the withdrawal");
 } else {
    System.out.println("Not enough in account for " 
                 + Thread.currentThread().getName() 
                 + " to withdraw " + acct.getBalance());
 }
 }
 }
```

I get the result like

1. Fred is going to withdraw
2. Fred completes the withdrawal
3. Fred is going to withdraw
4. Fred completes the withdrawal
5. Fred is going to withdraw
6. Fred completes the withdrawal
7. Fred is going to withdraw
8. Fred completes the withdrawal
9. Fred is going to withdraw
10. Fred completes the withdrawal
11. Not enough in account for Lucy to withdraw 0
12. Not enough in account for Fred to withdraw 0
13. Not enough in account for Lucy to withdraw 0
14. Not enough in account for Fred to withdraw 0
15. Not enough in account for Lucy to withdraw 0

However, the result of the book is like this:

1. Fred is going to withdraw
2. Fred completes the withdrawal
3. Lucy is going to withdraw
4. Lucy completes the withdrawal
5. Fred is going to withdraw
6. Fred completes the withdrawal
7. Lucy is going to withdraw
8. Lucy completes the withdrawal
9. Fred is going to withdraw
10. Fred completes the withdrawal
11. Not enough in account for Lucy to withdraw 0
12. Not enough in account for Fred to withdraw 0
13. Not enough in account for Lucy to withdraw 0
14. Not enough in account for Fred to withdraw 0
15. Not enough in account for Lucy to withdraw 0

Anyone can help me to explain why there is the difference. Thank you!

Comment: Do you get the same results every single time?

Comment: I think your result should have Lucy 5 times at the end, not both Lucy and Fred.

Comment: @Flavio he add the Thread.sleep(), that make the change

Comment: I tried many times the results are same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can happen in any order. I guess what the book wants to show is:
If there are multiple parties viz. `X` and `Y`
`X is going to withdraw` would be **strictly** followed by a `X completes the withdrawal` and **never** a `Y ...` because both of these statements are inside a `synchronized` method, which guarantees that **one and only one** thread can be executing that block of code at a given point of time.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your synchronized block is just for the function makeWithdrawal only.
First, Fred call makeWithdrawal, and block the calling to that function on other thread, once the function stop, every threads in queue take they turn to call. This case is Lucy.
To make Fred finish his work before let the other do, try to block all the content of run method, like this

```
public synchronized void run() {
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                + " Start calling");
        makeWithdrawal(10);
        if (acct.getBalance() < 0) {
            System.out.println("account is overdrawn!");
        }
    }
}
```

Or

```
public void run() {
    synchronized (this) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " Start calling");
            makeWithdrawal(10);
            if (acct.getBalance() < 0) {
                System.out.println("account is overdrawn!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have executed the code you provided. And the result is:

```
Fred is going to withdraw
Fred completes the withdrawal
Lucy is going to withdraw
Lucy completes the withdrawal
Fred is going to withdraw
Fred completes the withdrawal
Lucy is going to withdraw
Lucy completes the withdrawal
Lucy is going to withdraw
Lucy completes the withdrawal
Not enough in account for Fred to withdraw 0
Not enough in account for Fred to withdraw 0
Not enough in account for Fred to withdraw 0
Not enough in account for Lucy to withdraw 0
Not enough in account for Lucy to withdraw 0
```

This is completely different result that, what you have mentioned above.
When one thread is executing synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized method for same object is blocked until the first thread is done.
as when a synchronized method exits, it automatically establishes a happens-before relationship with any subsequent invocation of a synchronized method for the same object. Thus the output differentiates each time.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried your code, NetBeans warned me that I was using `Thread.sleep` in a synchronized block. What happens with it is that *as is it synchronized* the other thread can't run in the meanwhile and the wait does basically nothing.

I tried to put the sleep in the loop and the order is respected (even if Netbeans warns me about a `sleep in a loop` but it's pointless this time)